# What's wrong with cin >> num1, num2?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char choice;
  int solution, num1, num2;

  cout << "Menu";
  cout << "\n========";
  cout << "\n+) Add";
  cout << "\n-) subtract";
  cout << "\n*) Multiplication";
  cout << "\n/) Division";
  cout << "\nx) Exit";
  cout << endl;
  cout << "\nEnter your choice: ";
  cin >> choice;

  switch (choice) {
    case '+':
      cout << "\nEnter the operands: ";
      cin >> num1, num2;
      solution = num1 + num2;
      cout << num1 << '+' << num2 << '=' << solution;
      break;
    case '-':
      cout << "\nEnter the operands: ";
      cin >> num1, num2;
      solution = num1 + num2;
      cout << num1 << '-' << num2 << '=' << solution;
      break;
    case '*':
      cout << "\nEnter the operands: ";
      cin >> num1, num2;
      solution = num1 * num2;
      cout << num1 << '*' << num2 << '=' << solution;
      break;
    case '/':
      cout << "\nEnter the operands: ";
      cin >> num1, num2;
      solution = num1 / num2;
      cout << num1 << '/' << (double)num2 << '=' << solution;
      break;
    case 'x':
    case 'X':
      cout << "\nExiting....";
      return 0;
      break;
    default:
      cout << "\nInvalid choice";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

So i am writing a program which allows the user to input an operation. Its pretty much a calculator! I must use a switch statement. I feel like I am very close but now i have hit a brick wall. After the user inouts an operation the program runs and says it to enter the operands it is then supposed to do the operation with the numbers entered and the displays them. Theere is some type of problem after the user inputs the 2 operands where the program just crashes. Any suggestions as to what it may be?

Comment: reduce the amount of code, simplify the problem, then ask.  What is the simplest program you can come up with that still demonstrates the problem you are having?  Describe the problem better: what does "just crashes" mean?

Answer (score 8):

```
cin >> num1, num2;
```

This syntax is not correct for what you want. To chain, use

```
cin >> num1 >> num2;
```

If you compile with warnings you'll get notified about this by the compiler

```
int a{}, b{};
std::cin >> a, b;
```

gives the error:

```
warning: right operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
std::cin >> a, b;
```

The whole statement is parsed as

```
((std::cin >> a), b);
```

Which consists of two comma-separated expressions. The `b` in that case doesn't have any effect. If you print the variables after the `std::cin` line above, you will always get `0` for `b`

Comment: Darn! Didn't know that! appreciate the help!

Comment: @CaesarAguilar please note that you can (and should) accept an answer which solved your problem. You can do this by clicking the tick mark next to the answer.

Comment: @CaesarAguilar note that the real problem here was that you didn't understand how `std::cin` works. In the future try to create tiny examples (as I did) and then build up the pieces until you hit the point where something goes wrong and you don't understand it.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> int solution, num1, num2;
> ```

This leaves all variables uninitialised. Trying to read from them without a previous assignment is undefined behaviour.

> ```
> cin >> num1, num2;
> ```

The supposed intention of this line is to read into both variables. What happens really is an application of the [**comma operator**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator), with operands `cin >> num1` on the left side and `num2` on the right side.

The left side is evaluated and a value is written to `num1`; the second operand has no effect and leaves `num2` in its uninitialised status.

It's as if you had written `cin >> num1;`.

> ```
> solution = num1 + num2;
> ```

The aforementioned undefined behaviour happens, rendering your entire program invalid.

You can fix the problem as follows:

```
cin >> num1;
cin >> num2;
```

Comment: On the contrary, he disregards the _second_ operand, since comma has the lowest precedence.

Comment: @Ruslan: You are right. I'll fix my answer. Thanks!

Comment: thank you for the suggestions seemed to compile great with them! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are using cin wrong. Do this instead :

```
cin >> num1 >> num2;
```

(And it is always nice to let the user know what to type with one cout or two :)).

You could do cin only once just after `cin >> choice`, and before the `switch`. It will save you some lines and will respect the credo :

> Do not repeat yourself.

You don't check for divide by zero. If the user try to do `num1 / 0`, your program will crash.

The `return 0` in `case 'X'` is not necessary and your break won't be reached, so you could remove the return and you will meet the main's `return 0` instead, keeping the switch nice and clean.

In `case '/'` you cast `num2` to `double`. I don't see why you print the result of a `int` casted to a `double`. My guess is you wanted the result to be a `double`. In that case, you would do :

```
solution = num1 / (double)num2;
```

and change `solution` to be a `double`.

Lastly, I advise you always initialize your variables since you could face the case where you use unitialized variables and get undefined behavior.

Comment: really appreciate the help man. As i am a beginner your knowledge is very helpful!